Can I own a "trillion-dollar company" by selling 1 share out of 1 trillion for a dollar?
Let's say I start a new company with a trillion shares.
I then get my friend to invest a dollar in it in exchange for one share.
Two questions pop to mind:

What, if anything, prevents me from legitimately claiming the company is worth a trillion dollars?

If I can legitimately claim this, then why should we believe real-world (non-public) company valuations aren't similarly nonsensical?



Is this really a personal finance question?

Have you ever seen Dragon's Den / Shark Tank? They will often come on and go "I'd like 100k in return for 10% of my company" or something, and the Dragon / Shark will go "but why should I think your company is worth $1M?" - if you don't have something to back up that claim then it's useless. The "something" could be physical assets, IP, etc.

@Vicky: I have, but the very fact that different people looking at the same facts don't arrive at the same conclusion was exactly the basis for this question. What if my friend thought the company was worth a trillion and that's why he paid a dollar for a share? How is that different?

@BenMiller: ah I struggled to find out when searching, thanks!

Something is only "worth" what someone else is willing to pay for it, so only when you can get your friend to buy the other 999,999,999,999 shares for $1 Trillion do you really have a trillion dollar company.

@user541686 your suggestion is obviously fraud.  Why do you think committing fraud is a great way to start a business career?    You may want to seek professional help.

@PeteB. Fraud? Whom would be defrauded here, and how? The friend would know exactly what is going on...

@user541686 it's not fraud to your friend, but if you represent your friend as an independent investor to justify your valuation - that would be fraud.

@littleadv: Yeah that part I get.

Nothing, you can claim whatever you want. But if you try to collateralize the remaining shares, of sell them to someone who's not your friend - they'd want to conduct a proper valuation. A proper valuation will be using accounting principles and based on independently audited financial statements you'd have to provide.
Without proper accounting and audit - yes, these claims are not very useful.

Without a realistic valuation you wouldn't be able to list in the first place.  Even if you could, nobody would invest.

In short: If I pick up a rock off the ground and say it is worth a Trillion dollars, I can feel rich. However, until you can find someone to BUY that rock for a Trillion dollars, it isn't really worth that.
